# System level changes for JVM

Tags: java, operating-system

What are the architectural/system level changes has to made if I want to develop a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) like tool/application for Windows and Linux?

Basically, What are the architectural differences in JVM wrt Windows & Linux?

Thanks,

Naveen

Comment: What is a "system level change"? And to which piece of code would you want to make such a change? And please define "embed".

Since  a JVM does exist for Windows and Linux, I'd say you don't need to change those two at all to be able to write a JVM for them.

Comment: @Sauer, Yes you are right that JVM exist for both Windows & Linux. My question is what are the changes SUN has already made in JVM to port it on Windows as well as on Linux OS. I mean, what are the architectural differences in JVM wrt Windows & Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer here I think would be to point you at the [source code](http://openjdk.java.net/) and invite you to take a look.

"architectural differences" - Likely none. The architecture for the two VMs would likely be the same. What would differ is implementation of said architecture. The differences would be:
Anything that hits a native OS call. Two examples that fly to mind would be: Threads and UI.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good overview of what's involved in a JVM here:

http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm.html

I'd guess the language of choice for implementing a JVM would be C++, with the low level stuff like memory management, thread management, io, etc it would be interacting with the API provided by a particular OS.  Higher up features like bytecode interpretation could conceivably be common between platforms.

In terms of implementing something akin to a JVM, the answer to your question (and the difficulty of the task) would depend on the feature set you require.  Do however bear in mind, VMs (Java and others) are in part abstractions of the OS and typically mirror the features provided by the OS.